# Min and Max values of an array of dictionaries (JSON)

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, dictionary, max

I'm having trouble getting the maximum and the minimum values out of my dataset. I think this (// [Get the largest value from Json object with Javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2620922/get-the-largest-value-from-json-object-with-javascript) combined with [Math.min.apply returns 0 for null](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11817861/math-min-apply-returns-0-for-null)) comes closest to what I need, however my data is a bit more complicated (at least from my 'beginners point of view').

my dataset concerns life expectancy for all countries from 1995 till 2016 and looks like this:

```
[{"country":"Abkhazia","1995":null,"1996":null,"1997":null,"1998":null,"1999":null,"2000":null,"2001":null,"2002":null,"2003":null,"2004":null,"2005":null,"2006":null,"2007":null,"2008":null,"2009":null,"2010":null},
{"country":"Afghanistan","1995":null,"1996":null,"1997":null,"1998":null,"1999":null,"2000":null,"2001":null,"2002":5.7,"2003":6.8,"2004":6.4,"2005":6.6,"2006":6.8,"2007":7.3,"2008":7.0,"2009":7.6,"2010":7.6},
{"country":"Akrotiri and Dhekelia","1995":null,"1996":null,"1997":null,"1998":null,"1999":null,"2000":null,"2001":null,"2002":null,"2003":null,"2004":null,"2005":null,"2006":null,"2007":null,"2008":null,"2009":null,"2010":null},
{"country":"Albania","1995":2.6,"1996":4.0,"1997":4.8,"1998":5.3,"1999":5.8,"2000":6.4,"2001":6.0,"2002":6.3,"2003":6.2,"2004":6.9,"2005":6.8,"2006":6.7,"2007":6.9,"2008":6.7,"2009":6.9,"2010":6.5},
etc.
```

**What I need:**

The maximum value and the minimum value for the complete dataset.
For the example this would be:

```
min: 2.6
max: 7.6
```

I'm making a datamap using D3 and I want to use the values to create a range of colors.

**Code I tried**

As said in the introduction I think I need a combination of the two links given above, however I cannot make it work. For example, using the second link I van get the minimum value for a given country, but not the minimum of all countries.

Hope someone can help me!

Comment: please add a wanted result and the code, you tried.

Comment: The min and max for a year ? For every year ? By country ?

Comment: The overall structure of the array makes it difficult to work with it

Comment: NinaScholz and @Weedoze, is my question clear like this?

Comment: You could get the min/max of each country, and then the min/max of those.

Comment: So the result should be `min: 2.6, max: 7.6` ?

Comment: @Andreas, yes! Sorry, maybe I should've mentioned it like that. Kind of new to this site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could iterate over all countries and over all keys and check if the value is not equal to `null`. Then get `min` and `max` values.

```js
var data = [{ "country": "Abkhazia", "1995": null, "1996": null, "1997": null, "1998": null, "1999": null, "2000": null, "2001": null, "2002": null, "2003": null, "2004": null, "2005": null, "2006": null, "2007": null, "2008": null, "2009": null, "2010": null }, { "country": "Afghanistan", "1995": null, "1996": null, "1997": null, "1998": null, "1999": null, "2000": null, "2001": null, "2002": 5.7, "2003": 6.8, "2004": 6.4, "2005": 6.6, "2006": 6.8, "2007": 7.3, "2008": 7.0, "2009": 7.6, "2010": 7.6 }, { "country": "Akrotiri and Dhekelia", "1995": null, "1996": null, "1997": null, "1998": null, "1999": null, "2000": null, "2001": null, "2002": null, "2003": null, "2004": null, "2005": null, "2006": null, "2007": null, "2008": null, "2009": null, "2010": null }, { "country": "Albania", "1995": 2.6, "1996": 4.0, "1997": 4.8, "1998": 5.3, "1999": 5.8, "2000": 6.4, "2001": 6.0, "2002": 6.3, "2003": 6.2, "2004": 6.9, "2005": 6.8, "2006": 6.7, "2007": 6.9, "2008": 6.7, "2009": 6.9, "2010": 6.5 }],
    min = Number.MAX_VALUE,
    max = -Number.MAX_VALUE;

data.forEach(function (o) {
    Object.keys(o).forEach(function (k) {                
        if (k !== 'country' && o[k] !== null) {
            min = Math.min(min, o[k]);
            max = Math.max(max, o[k]);
        }
    });
});

console.log(min, max);
```

Answer (score 1):

If you are permitted to use ES6:

```
const maxValue = dataset.reduce( (max, obj)  => {
    let ar = [max];
    for(const key in obj) {
        if (isNaN(Number.parseFloat(obj[key]))) continue;
        ar.push(obj[key]):
    }
    return Math.max.apply(ar, Math);
}, -1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming you want to check all of the elements of your array for a valid number, and get the min/max of the resulting number set. Here is a code sample to do that. You can click run to see the result.

```js
data = [{"country":"Abkhazia","1995":null,"1996":null,"1997":null,"1998":null,"1999":null,"2000":null,"2001":null,"2002":null,"2003":null,"2004":null,"2005":null,"2006":null,"2007":null,"2008":null,"2009":null,"2010":null},
{"country":"Afghanistan","1995":null,"1996":null,"1997":null,"1998":null,"1999":null,"2000":null,"2001":null,"2002":5.7,"2003":6.8,"2004":6.4,"2005":6.6,"2006":6.8,"2007":7.3,"2008":7.0,"2009":7.6,"2010":7.6},
{"country":"Akrotiri and Dhekelia","1995":null,"1996":null,"1997":null,"1998":null,"1999":null,"2000":null,"2001":null,"2002":null,"2003":null,"2004":null,"2005":null,"2006":null,"2007":null,"2008":null,"2009":null,"2010":null},
{"country":"Albania","1995":2.6,"1996":4.0,"1997":4.8,"1998":5.3,"1999":5.8,"2000":6.4,"2001":6.0,"2002":6.3,"2003":6.2,"2004":6.9,"2005":6.8,"2006":6.7,"2007":6.9,"2008":6.7,"2009":6.9,"2010":6.5}];

values = [];

for (i in data) {
  for (j in data[i]) {
    if (parseFloat(data[i][j]) > 0) {
      values.push(parseFloat(data[i][j]));
    }
  }
}

min = Math.min.apply(null, values);
max = Math.max.apply(null, values);
alert(values)
alert(min);
alert(max);
```